# How To Connect mysql server from another machine in same lan

Tags: mysql, connection

Hi all
I have created a new web application in php/mysql. my using windows7 and xampp.. now i have another desktop application written in c# which is installed in another machine in same lan.
For some reason that application needs to share mysql database with web application..... i googled for the solution .... there were few suggestion to change

***bind-address = 0.0.0.0***

in xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini and i did that but it is not still working i comment

## skip-networking

## enable-named-pipe

also change ***host = .*** to ***host = %***
but i could not connect.... is there any solution.... i have spend 8 hours searching here and there and trying different things but no luck.... also my firewalls are turned off

thanks in advance
Surace

Answer (score 0):

OK, say if you're on a LAN of 192.168.0.x, then what i've done in the past when doing web dev and mysql is to connect to 192.168.0.2:3306, if i'm on a different ip address, hope this helps :) I've never used C# so apologies if this is useless!

Comment: thanks for your reply... i solved the problem ... i used wamp instead and grant all privileges to the user using mysql console.... and turn off the fire wall.... no change in my.ini .... skip-netwokring was commented by default... no need to bind-adress...